# How to cancel previous onClick handler that has two dispatch functions with useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I saw this https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-while-running
but I have two dispatch functions inside an `onClick` handler.
How can I put them into `useEffect()`?

I want to achieve when user quickly clicks on another item, the previous `fetchFileContentsHandler` will be cancelled, and always return the result from the latest invoke.

I tried to wrap `fetchFileContentsHandler` in `useCallback()`,
and put `fetchFileContentsHandler` inside `useEffect()` with clean up return.
but it resulted in strange behavior.

```
  const fetchFileContentsHandler = () => {
    dispatch(fetchFileContents(props.params));
    dispatch(
      changeSelectedFile({ selectedFile: props.params, selected: true })
    );
  };

  return (
    <NavLink to="#" key={fileName}>
      <ListItemButton
        selected={props.selected}
        onClick={fetchFileContentsHandler}
      >
        <ListItemText
          primary={fileName}
        />
      </ListItemButton>
    </NavLink>
  );
};

export default Items;
```

---

**[update]**
I tried to change `fetchFileContents` to `createAsyncThunk` and add the suggested `useRef()` and `.abort()`, but it didn't work.

If the first `fetchFileContents` takes longer than the second `fetchFileContents`, it still updates the `htmlReport` or `textReport` value once it's fulfilled.

Then once `htmlReport` or `textReport` value changes, I display its contents in another component. So I can still see the first fetched file contents display after the second fetched file contents.

slice.js

```js
export const fetchFileContents = createAsyncThunk(
  "ui/getFileContents",
  async (fileName) => {
    const fileContentsResponse = await fetch(...);
    const response = await fileContentsResponse.json();

    return {
      fileType: fileName.includes("html") ? "text" : "html",
      contents: data,
    };
  }
);
const Slice = createSlice({
  name: "somename",
  initialState: {
    htmlReport: null,
    textReport: null,
  },
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchFileContents.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        if (action.payload.fileType === "text") {
          state.textReport = action.payload.contents;
          state.htmlReport = null;
        } else if (action.payload.fileType === "html") {
          state.textReport = null;
          state.htmlReport = action.payload.contents;
        }
      })
      .addCase(fetchFileContents.rejected, (state, action) => {
        console.log("[REJECTED]: ");
        const { fileName } = action.meta.arg;
        const { message } = action.error;
        console.log(fileName, message);
      });
  },
});
```

Component.js

```js
const fetchFileContentsPromise = useRef();

  const fetchFileContentsHandler = () => {
    fetchFileContentsPromise.current?.abort();

    fetchFileContentsPromise.current = dispatch(
      fetchFileContents({ fileName: props.params })
    );
    dispatch(
      changeSelectedFile({ selectedFile: props.params, selected: true })
    );
  };
```

**[update]**
I can't find any major differences between your codes and mine.
Your log was correctly recorded:

```
undefined
Fetching data with A...
Promise .....{fileName: 'A'.....
Fetching data with C...
[REJECTED]: A, I canceled it.
Promise resolved: CCC
[FULFILLED]: CCC
Promise resolved: AAA
```

But my log looks like this:

```
undefined
Fetching data with A...
undefined
Fetching data with C...
[FULFILLED]: CCC
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 55ms
[FULFILLED]: AAA
```

or when I repeat:

```
Promise .....{fileName: 'A'.....
Fetching data with A...
Promise .....{fileName: 'C'.....
Fetching data with C...
[FULFILLED]: CCC
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 55ms
[FULFILLED]: AAA
```

---

**[update -- Solved]**
I figured out that I had to declare `const fetchFileContentsPromise = useRef();` in the parent component and use props to send it to the child then send it to child's child again.

I use a nested object and pick the necessary values to parent -> child(1) -> child(2).
This `fetchFileContents` is in child(2).

But I don't understand why.

I would be really appreciated it if anyone could explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close!

If you scroll down a little bit in [the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-while-running) you found, you'll see that it says the `dispatch(asyncThunk)` will return a promise with an `abort` method.

In your use case, we only want previous requests to be canceled when the button is click.
`useEffect` could work, but we'll have to create some extra state to put it in the dependencies array, which is kind of weird.

Another possible option is to use `useRef` to store those promises, so that we don't have to deal with `useEffect`. I'm not sure if both of the actions are async thunk, if yes you can try:

```js
const fetchFileContentsPromise = useRef()
const changeSelectedFilePromise = useRef()

const fetchFileContentsHandler = () => {
  // Cancel previous requests
  fetchFileContentsPromise.current?.abort();
  changeSelectedFilePromise.current?.abort();

  // Dispatch actions and send new requests
  fetchFileContentsPromise.current = dispatch(fetchFileContents(props.params));
  changeSelectedFilePromise.current = dispatch(
    changeSelectedFile({ selectedFile: props.params, selected: true })
  );
}
```

If `changeSelectedFile` is not an action created by `createAsyncThunk`, then it's really not possible to stop that because it's synchronous.

In that case I would suggest you to move the logic in `changeSelectedFile` into the [extra reducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#extrareducers) when `fetchFileContents` is fulfilled, so that we only execute those code when `fetchFileContents` is done.

Comment: The solution didn't work, please @abemscac could you see my [update] in the post? thank you. I found `changeSelectedFile` should not be aborted, so I didn't change it.

Comment: That's strange, I think for some reason your thunk is not correctly canceled. Could you please take a look at [this sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gekchi?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FCounter.js), and see if your reducer can catch rejected case like this one do. A canceled thunk will fall to the rejected case in extra reducer.

Comment: You are right, it is not correctly canceled. I have put reject in `extraReducers`. I updated the log observation in the post. Do you have any idea how it could be different? Thank you so much for the example codes !! It really helps a lot.

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks a lot! Please see my last two updates in the post. Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: It's great to know it's finally working! I'm not really sure what makes your component not able to `useRef` in child like the sandbox do. I tried to reproduce the problem in a sandbox, but didn't make it. Maybe you could provide a sandbox for us to reproduce the issue & try to find the cause!